# Zoom in to the object based on mouse pointer

Tags: javascript, d3.js, three.js

Here I'm trying to zoom in the object(say cube) based on the on mouse pointer position. Here I googled and got a idea that it can be achieved in D3 JS and also it can achieved by capturing the mouse pointer 3D point and passing it in the mouse wheel function.

Here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fpt9hswo/

```
var scene, renderer, camera;
var cube;
var controls;
var containerWidth = window.innerWidth,
  containerHeight = window.innerHeight;

init();
animate();

function init() {
  configureRenderer();

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  configureCube();

  configureCamera();

  configureLight();

  configureControls();

  fitAll();
}

function configureRenderer() {
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true,
    alpha: true
  });
  renderer.setSize(containerWidth, containerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

function configureCube() {
  var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(20, 20, 20);
  var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: 0xff0000
  });
  cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);
  cube.position.set(50, 0, 0);
  scene.add(cube);
}

function configureCamera() {
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, containerWidth / containerHeight, 1, 1000);
  camera.position.set(0, 160, 400);
  camera.lookAt(scene);
}

function configureLight() {
  pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1.0, 100000);
  pointLight.position.set(0, 300, 200);
  scene.add(pointLight);
}

function configureControls() {
  controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
   // configuration of controls
  controls.rotateSpeed = 5.0;
  controls.zoomSpeed = 5.0;
  controls.panSpeed = 2.0;
  controls.staticMoving = true;
  controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0;
}

function fitAll() {
  // Calculate bounding box of the whole scene
  var boundingBoxOfNode = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(scene),
    centerOfGravity = boundingBoxOfNode.getCenter();

 /************* CAMERA *************************/
  camera.position.addVectors(camera.position, centerOfGravity);
  camera.lookAt(centerOfGravity);
  //new camera positions will be set here
  //Eg: camera.position.set(newCamera.x,newCamera.y,newCamera.z);
  //Similarly new camera rotation and quaternion coordinates will be set
  //Eg: camera.rotation.set(newCamera.rotatex,newCamera.rotatey,newCamera.rotatez);
  //Eg: camera.quaternion.set(newCamera.qw,newCamera.qx,newCamera.qy,newCamera.qz);

  /*************    CONTROLS *************************/
  controls.target.set(centerOfGravity.x, centerOfGravity.y, centerOfGravity.z);
  //new controls.target values will be set here
  //Eg: controls.target.set(newCamera.targetx,newCamera.targety,newCamera.targetz);
}

function animate() {
  controls.update();
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you press the mousewheel button while pulling back on the mouse, the camera zooms.. Is that what you're talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do what you want you've to implement your own mouse wheel event and you've to disable the default zoom of `THREE.TrackballControls`:

```js
controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
//...
controls.zoomSpeed = 0.0;
```

Add a wheel event:

e.g.

```js
renderer.domElement.addEventListener("wheel", event => {
    const delta = event.deltaY;

    // [...]
}
```

Zooming in perspective projection can be achieved, by shifting the camera position in the depth of the world.
If you want to zoom to a point, this can be achieved by moving the camera along a ray, from the camera position through the cursor (mouse) position and to move the target position in parallel.

A point on the ray from the camera to the cursor in normalized device space can be found with ease. In normalized device space all coordinates are in range [-1, 1] and all points with the same *x* and *y* coordinate are at the same ray. If the *z* coordinate is -1, the the point is on the near plane and if *z* is 1 then the point is on the far plane.

e.g. NDC point on the far plane and on a ray through the cursor:

```js
let x = 2 * event.clientX / window.innerWidth - 1; 
let y = 1 - 2 * event.clientY / window.innerHeight;
let cursorpos = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, 1);
```

This point in normalized device space can be transformed to a point in world space, by [`THREE.Vector3.unproject()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.unproject). The parameter to the function has to be the [`THREE.Camera`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/cameras/Camera) which defines the view and projection:

```js
cursorpos.unproject(camera);
```

The direction for the movement of the camera is the normalized direction from the camera position to the cursor position in world space:

```js
let dir = new THREE.Vector3().copy(cursorpos).sub(camera.position).normalize();
```

Calculate the movement dependent on the direction and the mouse wheel delta and update the camera and  `THREE.TrackballControls`:

```js
let shift = new THREE.Vector3().copy(dir).multiplyScalar(delta * 0.1);

camera.position.add(shift);
controls.position0.add(shift);
controls.target.add(shift);
```

See the example, where I applied the suggestions to the code of the question:

```js
var scene, renderer, camera;
var cube;
var controls;
var containerWidth = window.innerWidth,
  containerHeight = window.innerHeight;

init();

animate();

function init() {
  configureRenderer();

  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  configureCube();
  configureCamera();
  configureLight();
  configureControls();
}

function configureRenderer() {
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true,
    alpha: true
  });
  renderer.setSize(containerWidth, containerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  window.onresize = function() {
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      if (controls)
          controls.handleResize();
  }

  renderer.domElement.addEventListener("wheel", event => {
      const delta = event.deltaY;

      let x = 2 * event.clientX / window.innerWidth - 1; 
      let y = 1 - 2 * event.clientY / window.innerHeight;
      let cursorpos = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, 1);

      cursorpos.unproject(camera); 

      let dir = new THREE.Vector3().copy(cursorpos).sub(camera.position).normalize();
      let shift = new THREE.Vector3().copy(dir).multiplyScalar(delta * 0.1);

      camera.position.add(shift);
      controls.position0.add(shift);
      controls.target.add(shift);
  });
}

function configureCube() {
  var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(20, 20, 20);
  var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: 0xff0000
  });
  cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);
  cube.position.set(50, 0, 0);
  scene.add(cube);
}

function configureCamera() {
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, containerWidth / containerHeight, 1, 1000);
  camera.position.set(0, 160, 400);
  camera.lookAt(scene);
}

function configureLight() {
  pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1.0, 100000);
  pointLight.position.set(0, 300, 200);
  scene.add(pointLight);
}

function configureControls() {
  controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  // configuration of controls
  controls.rotateSpeed = 5.0;
  controls.zoomSpeed = 0.0;
  controls.panSpeed = 2.0;
  controls.staticMoving = true;
  controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0;
}

function animate() {
  controls.update();
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
```